# google cloud storage download for IOS/Android App

Tags: android, ios, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to download single big file as multiple thread and combine all once downloaded  from google cloud storage.

Comment: Yep, Brandon's answer below should get you started. It's worth noting, however, that maxing out the phone's connectivity could be a bit rough on the battery, and might degrade performance of other applications if you're doing it in a background task. Network bandwidth in general costs users a lot of battery (and possibly money) so you might want to tread lightly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When downloading objects from Google Cloud storage, you can specify a byte range that you would like to retrieve. Using the XML API, this would be handled via the "Range:" header. This is useful for resuming interrupted downloads, but it can also be used to download the file with multiple threads.

Here's some documentation on how to format the range parameter: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#range

And here's the documentation for the get object call, including the Range header:
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#getobject

Comment: Thanks for your responce, but I did tried this before and ended with multiple time app crass.  Is there a way to do the same with Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

you can use android's DownloadManager class, its best for downloading files with larger sizes
please see link below
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html